# Connect two div with a line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to reproduce a clock with material design (without jquery). But I cant manage to make line between two div with generated elements.
the coordinate are obviously wrong, I've been trying others solution tha i found on this website but nothing works.
Here's the code :

```js
'use strict';

(function () {
    var hourPicker = document.querySelectorAll(".hourPicker");
    for (var i = 0; i < hourPicker.length; i++) {
        var circle = hourPicker[i].querySelector(".circle");
        var txt = "";
        var angle = 360 / 12;
        var s = 90;
        var hours = ["6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
        for (var i2 = 0; i2 < 12; i2++) {

            txt += '<div class="item" style=" transform: rotate(' + s + 'deg) translate(6rem) rotate(-' + s + 'deg);">' + hours[i2] + '</div>';
            s += angle
        }
        circle.innerHTML = txt;
        var item = circle.querySelectorAll(".item");


        for(var ii = 0 ; ii <item.length ; ii++)
        console.log(item[ii].innerHTML +':'+ item[ii].getBoundingClientRect().top +";" + item[ii].getBoundingClientRect().left);




        var y2 = item[1].getBoundingClientRect().top;
        var x2 = item[1].getBoundingClientRect().left;


        var x1 = circle.offsetWidth / 2;
        var y1 = circle.offsetHeight / 2;

        circle.innerHTML += '<svg width="500" height="500"><line x1="' + x1 + '" y1="' + y1 + '" x2="' + x2 + '" y2="' + y2 + '" stroke="black"/></svg>';
    }

})();
```

```css
*{
  
}
body{
    font-size: 50%; 
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
main{
    margin: 5rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
.hourPicker{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}

.hourPicker .head{
    text-align: right;
    padding: 1rem 2rem; 
    background: #009688;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: white;
    
}
.hourPicker .body{
    position: relative;
    margin:  2rem 1rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.hourPicker .circle {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    height: 15rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 15rem;
  
}
.hourPicker .item{
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: .8rem;
    opacity: .7;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%; 
    left: 45%;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
}
.hourPicker .item:hover{
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #009688;
    color: white;
}
.hourPicker .center_circle{
    position: absolute;
    background: #009688;
    width: .5rem;
    height: .5rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    
}
.hourPicker .arrow_circle{
    position: absolute;
    width: 5.5rem;
    background: #009688;
    height: 0.1rem;
    right: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/Normalize.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hour.css">
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <div class="hourPicker">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="hour">15:30</div>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <div class="circle"></div>
                <div class="center_circle"></div>
                <!--<div class="arrow_circle"></div>-->
                <!--<svg width="500" height="500"><line x1="50" y1="50" x2="350" y2="350" stroke="black"/></svg>  -->
            </div>
            <div class="bottom"></div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="hour.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks a lot.
Thomas

Comment: If you just want a basic clock, you could use canvas. Take a look: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_clock_start.asp

Comment: thanks for your answer , but I need to interact with this clock, like  this https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_11/assets/0B3321sZLoP_HUG5QV0EzWTAxS2s/components_pickers_time_transition.mp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing HTML & SVG elements might be little tricky, and you can make canvas receive clicks as well, but still, what you need here is to take into account that SVG is relative to circle, and getBoundingClientRect not, also getBoundingClientRect gives you top left corner, not middle of eleement;

EDI: added pointer-events: none to SVG to prevent if from interfering with clicks.hover;

```js
'use strict';

(function () {
    var hourPicker = document.querySelectorAll(".hourPicker");
    for (var i = 0; i < hourPicker.length; i++) {
        var circle = hourPicker[i].querySelector(".circle");
        var txt = "";
        var angle = 360 / 12;
        var s = 90;
        var hours = ["6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
        for (var i2 = 0; i2 < 12; i2++) {

            txt += '<div class="item" style=" transform: rotate(' + s + 'deg) translate(6rem) rotate(-' + s + 'deg);">' + hours[i2] + '</div>';
            s += angle
        }
        circle.innerHTML = txt;
        var item = circle.querySelectorAll(".item");


        for(var ii = 0 ; ii <item.length ; ii++)
        console.log(item[ii].innerHTML +':'+ item[ii].getBoundingClientRect().top +";" + item[ii].getBoundingClientRect().left);


  console.log(item[1])

        var y2 = item[1].getBoundingClientRect().top;
        var x2 = item[1].getBoundingClientRect().left;
        
        var w2 = item[1].getBoundingClientRect().width;
        var h2 = item[1].getBoundingClientRect().height;
        
        var circlePos = circle.getBoundingClientRect();


        var x1 = circle.offsetWidth / 2;
        var y1 = circle.offsetHeight / 2;

        circle.innerHTML += '<svg width="240" height="240"><line x1="' + x1 + '" y1="' + y1 + '" x2="' + ((x2-circlePos.left)+w2/2) + '" y2="' + ((y2-circlePos.top)+h2/2) + '" stroke="black"/></svg>';
    }

})();
```

```css
*{
  
}
body{
    font-size: 50%; 
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
main{
    margin: 5rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
.hourPicker{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}

.hourPicker .head{
    text-align: right;
    padding: 1rem 2rem; 
    background: #009688;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: white;
    
}
.hourPicker .body{
    position: relative;
    margin:  2rem 1rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.hourPicker .circle {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    height: 15rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 15rem;
  
}
.hourPicker .item{
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: .8rem;
    opacity: .7;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%; 
    left: 45%;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
}
.hourPicker .item:hover{
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #009688;
    color: white;
}
.hourPicker .center_circle{
    position: absolute;
    background: #009688;
    width: .5rem;
    height: .5rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    
}
.hourPicker .arrow_circle{
    position: absolute;
    width: 5.5rem;
    background: #009688;
    height: 0.1rem;
    right: 2rem;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/Normalize.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hour.css">
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <div class="hourPicker">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="hour">15:30</div>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <div class="circle"></div>
                <div class="center_circle"></div>
                <!--<div class="arrow_circle"></div>-->
                <!--<svg width="500" height="500"><line x1="50" y1="50" x2="350" y2="350" stroke="black"/></svg>  -->
            </div>
            <div class="bottom"></div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="hour.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks  for explications, it is exatly what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be along the lines of what you want. It's an analog clock made in HTML and Javascript http://www.encodedna.com/html5/canvas/simple-analog-clock-using-canvas-javascript.htm

Comment: Thank for your answer two.  , but I need to interact with this clock, like this https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_11/assets/0B3321sZLoP_HUG5QV0EzWTAxS2s/components_pickers_time_transition.mp4

Comment: So sorry about that. https://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/gfx/demos/clock.html how about this one? you can interact with it (move the hands and reset) just view the source code and it should be fairly simple to replicate